# Kubernetes Front and Back end communication

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, kubectl

I have been struggling for a few hours on this one. I have a very simple 2 tier  dotnet core skeleton app (mvc and webapi) hosted on Azure using Kubernetes with Windows as the orchestrator.
The deployment works fine and I can pass basic environment variables over. The challenge I have is that I cannot determine how to pass the backend service IP address over to the frontend variables.
if I stage the deployments, I can manually pass the exposed IP of the backend into the frontend. Ideally, this needs to be deployed as a service.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Deployment commands:**

1 - kubectl create -f backend-deploy.yaml

2 - kubectl create -f backend-service.yaml

3 - kubectl create -f frontend-deploy.yaml

4 - kubectl create -f frontend-service.yaml

**backend-deploy.yaml**

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: acme
spec:
  replicas: 5
  template:
metadata:
  labels:
    app: acme-app
    tier: backend
spec:
  containers:
    - name: backend-container
      image: "some/image"
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: supersecretkey
      env:
      - name: Config__AppName
        value: "Acme App"
      - name: Config__AppDescription
        value: "Just a backend application"
      - name: Config__AppVersion
        value: "1.0"
      - name: Config__CompanyName
        value: "Acme Trading Limited"
```

**backend-service.yaml**

```html
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: acme-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: acme-app
    tier: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**frontend-deploy.yaml**

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: acme-app
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontend-container
          image: "some/image"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: supersecretkey
          env:
          - name: Config__AppName
            value: "Acme App"
          - name: Config__AppDescription
            value: "Just a frontend application"
          - name: Config__AppVersion
            value: "1.0"
          - name: Config__AppTheme
            value: "fx-theme-black"
          - name: Config__ApiUri
            value: ***THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE BACKEND SERVICE IP***
          - name: Config__CompanyName
            value: "Acme Trading Limited"
```

**frontend-service.yaml**

```html
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    app: acme
    tier: frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: You should add `type: LoadBalancer` for your backend too. That way the *user browser* running your frontend code can connect to it.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my src to reflect this.

Comment: services are exposed within pods as env vars. Just connect to a running pod and run `printenv` to confirm yourself.

Comment: Something like this... value: $(BACKEND_SERVICE_HOST):$(BACKEND_SERVICE_PORT)?

Comment: from front end you can connect using DNS `acme-app.default.svc.cluster.local`. default is the name space, If your running your app in different name space, replace the default with your name space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your backend service was created BEFORE the frontend pods, you should have the environment variables `ACME_APP_SERVICE_HOST` and `ACME_APP_SEVICE_PORT` inside the pods.

If your backend service was created AFTER the frontend pods, then delete the pods and wait for them to be restarted. The new pods should have those variables.

To check the environment variables do:

```
$ kubectl exec podName env
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It has brought me a step closer. I can now bring the cluster IP address of the backend service into the frontend although I am now seeing the error... ***net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED***. I will keep digging around to see whats going on.